Timer scheduleAtFixedRate is discouraged
I've come across suggestions that using of scheduleAtFixedRate is strongly discouraged because it can lead to unexpected behavior when Android processes become cached (tasks may unexpectedly execute hundreds or thousands of times in quick succession when a process changes from cached to uncached). Can someone elaborate on this? What are the specific concerns regarding scheduleAtFixedRate in Android, and what alternative approaches are recommended for handling periodic tasks in Android applications?

The documentation stipulates the behavior of Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate():

In fixed-rate execution, each execution is scheduled relative to the scheduled execution time of the initial execution.

Because the execution of the TimerTask is scheduled at a precise moment relative relative to the initial scheduling time, when a process is uncached, there will be many scheduled executions that would need to execute right away because their scheduled execution time was in the past.
Imagine the following timing:

0:00: App is launched and an execution is scheduled using scheduleAtFixedRate(timer, 10000L, 10000L)
0:10: First execution
0:15: User leaves app and the process is cached
0:20: Second execution is missed
0:25: User resumes app and the process is uncached
0:25: Second execution ← this is likely unexpected and why the Lint warning is there
0:30: Third execution

